# How to register dll extension with EsriRegAsm.exe?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, windows, development

I am having some issues with registering a dll:

1. run DOS as Administrator
2. CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin\" (where the ESRIRegAsm.exe is)
3. I attempt to register the dll as follows:

Syntax:  ESRIRegAsm.exe assembly_name /p:product_name

ESRIRegAsm.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyExtension\myextension.dll" /p:desktop

I get a warning raised by the registration utility that says: Specified path not found.

However, the path is positively correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Please re-enter your comment and enter as an answer so that i may mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change to the directory of the DLL that you need to register you should be able to type *just* the DLL name without having to worry about directory names with spaces.

So, in your case, cd to "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyExtension" and then run the following:

```
ESRIRegAsm myextension.dll /p:desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small script to make deploying the dll a little easier. Save and distribute as [`esri-register-dlls.bat`](https://gist.github.com/maphew/6f48135abb77fc68d68427a119882f8f) in same folder as the tool.

```
@echo off
echo.
echo. Manually registering custom ArcGIS COM tools in the current folder...
echo.
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\ArcGIS\bin

for %%a in (*.dll) do ESRIRegAsm.exe "%%~dpna"

endlocal
```

If you need to also enable 64bit background processing: use the `/regfile:somename.reg` parameter to create registration file and then import using regedit.exe, which will automatically create the 64bit regsitry hive version.

```
ESRIRegAsm "path\to\custom.dll" /regfile:custom-tool.reg
regedit "path\to\custom-tool.reg"
```

Source: [How To: Register function tools (DLL) for both Desktop and 64-bit Background Processing](http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011695) (Esri tech article)